# PyautgoGui on AWS receive errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, beautifulsoup, pyautogui

I'm currently working on implementing web scraping via a web server (amazon was). Had some problem with ubuntu (currently running windows 10) The script works perfectly fine until I close the section. For some reason when I close it I receive this error:

> Build Failed, Reason: PyAutoGUI fail-safe triggered from mouse moving
> to a corner of the screen. To disable this fail-safe, set
> pyautogui.FAILSAFE to False. DISABLING FAIL-SAFE IS NOT RECOMMENDED.

I don't experience any other problem if I have the connection open. I checked and the display size stays the same. Are there any fixes to this?

Comment: You can disable the PyAutoGUI failsafe with `pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False` at the top of your code, after your `import` section, which will prevent that error from occurring but you won't be able to trigger the failsafe anymore by moving your mouse to top left corner of the screen.

Comment: @Samuel Liew I believe this question shouldn't have been closed, it had enough details for me to figure out what's going on and I provided a solution.

Comment: @Andrew reopened.